# How to suppress typescript errors when compiling a single file by nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I use Node.js to compile a single TypeScript file from project, which has dependencies on other files I get multiple "Could not find symbol .." errors. Despite these errors JS file is created correctly. There are no explicit references in TypeScript files.

Is there a way to suppress these errors? Or tell compiler where to look for dependencies, but not recompile all files?

The reason I want to do this is performance. My goal is to use Grunt to watch for TypeScript files. On change it would compile them to JS, do some transformations, minimize, bundle and run unit tests. However, only a single step to compile all 160 typescript files to JS takes around 8 seconds, which is painfully slow for development process. Compiling only single changed file should speed it up.

Comment: You can add `any` as type for objects with no-defined types, otherwise you can use --noresolve compiler directive in the command line arguments.

Comment: --noresolve command line argument doesn't change a thing. I run it as "tsc file.ts --noresolve", but still getting all my "could not find symbol ..." errors. Changing types to "any" is not an option, type is the reason I use TypeScript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an option at the moment. I've been planning on adding it to grunt-ts for `/// <reference`'s   https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts/issues/34 but the same can apply for node.